# ERROR ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android

Falla la aplicacion por el spinner_adapter, alguna ayuda?

```
        TextView spinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ArrayAdapter spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_amazon_venta, R.id.textView , cantidadValores);
        spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Vender:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonInvertirTick"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/success" />
```

ERROR:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.iberd.actionvalue, PID: 21989
>                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID
>   to be a TextView
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:592)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:416)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:388)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194) 
>                                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:592) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:416) 
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)

Comment: Creo que **el problema en sí no es el Spinner**. Es posible que en tu XML **tengas un TextView y un RelativeLayout con el mismo id**, por lo que dice el mensaje de error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView...`

Answer (score 1):

Si estas instanciando de esta forma el `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_amazon_venta, 0 , cantidadValores);
```

el tercer parámetro debe ser el id del `TextView` que se encuentra dentro del layout `activity_amazon_venta.xml`, no es valido un 0 como Id.

---

Mencionas que tu layout es contiene un `Spinner`, lo cual es incorrecto, como ejemplo, el layout debe ser similar a :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

y tu Adapter se crearía de esta forma (el tercer parámetro es el id del `TextView` dentro del Layout) :

```
ArrayAdapter spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_amazon_venta, R.id.textView , cantidadValores);
```

Comment: he cambiado el xml y el codigo aunque ahora al quitar el spinner no puedo hacer un setAdapter de un TextView. Actualizo la cuestion